# Reinforcement learning, pendulum python

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

I'm having trouble finding a good reward function for the pendulum problem, the function I'm using: -x ** 2 + - 0.25 * (xdot ** 2)
which is the quadratic error from the top. with x representing the current location of the pendulum and xdot the angular velocity.

its takes a lot of time with this function and sometimes doesn't work.
any one have some other suggestions?
I've been looking in google but didn't find anything i could use

Comment: I guess you should rather post this to cross-validated or even datascience stack communities; overflow is dedicated to technical aspects, ie coding, not methodology.

Comment: Many things can influence the speed of convergence and its effectiveness, particularly the learning algorithm (Q-learning, SARSA, Deep Q-learning), the learning rate and the size of the space state. Could you please develop your question a little bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5719642/), the authors perform different experiments in a simulated and a real version of the inverted pendulum with the following reward function:
[image]

here, `x` is the state vector representing the current angle and angular velocity, and `u` is the action.

Experiments show that the reward function works reasonably well using the following algorithms: SARSA, LSPI, experience replay SARSA and experience replay Q-learning.

However, take into account that your problem maybe is not (only) related with the reward function, since the speed of convergence can be affect by many factors, as suggested by @Matheus Portela in the comments.